# How to store credentials in Web application to access webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms, forms-authentication

I am working on an application where I need to store a user credentials to access webservice to perform different operations through out user session and finally destroy the credentials.

1.User Enters credentials in Login Screen (Using Forms Authentication)
2. I am Capturing credentials and storing it in session as below:

```
   Webservice webService = new Webservice();
    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    cache.Add(new Uri(webService.Url), // Web service URL
               "Negotiate",        // Kerberos or NTLM
               new NetworkCredential(userName, pwd, domain));       
    webService.Credentials = cache;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["webService"] = webService;
```

I am not sure whether this is a correct way of doing it or not. As I need this webservice object throughout the session scope I am using above logic.

Please some one suggest me how can I accomplish this.

My application is not a SSL enabled application(Http).

Comment: 1. U can try the credentials writing in a file, then deleting the contents when u want
2. U can set static variables at the launch of the application with the creds' values
3. U can additionally use a cryptographically strong credential-specific salt [protected form] = [salt] + protect([protection func], [salt] + [credential]);

Comment: If I declare it as a static variable, Do these variables  get override when other user login to application ?

Comment: Taking the user login and password and storing it in the session will work. It will go away after the session ends. It is a viable way to handle it.

Comment: Is it secure and Best practice to store it in session ? And do I also need to use cryptography(salt) to make it strong ? @RegencySoftware

Comment: Hmmm, good point, Create an array equal to the number of Users & I hoping there is no mult- logins of same user. Use the array value as accordingly the no of users gets logged in.... Is ur App capable of identifying the no of current logins? If yes this is very much do-able

Comment: @Shubhojit Thank You for your time,No My app is not capable enough to identity current logins.

Comment: Is it possible for u to add an XML file, with some security features of course, U can add into it mapped with user with SALT or any other alogo

Comment: U can use DB also in fact if u do not want to use anything in Application for remembering, u can use same hashing techniques of save id/password with currentuserid.... I have seen linking tables in enterprise solutions doing just do that to avoid overhead to the cache

Comment: @Shubhojit Sure that's a great idea, I will give  a try. Other solution I got is storing credentials in session, Is storing credentials in session is it best practice

Comment: @RaghunathAnne, that depends on the nature of the app u r building, if too much of sessions here & there, the avg throughput increases & infra issues will start coming. Its always good \to start safe rather than sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125618/discussion-between-raghunath-anne-and-shubhojit).